# Solving system of equations for rational numbers

Tags: functions

**Question**: How many rational number ordered triples $(x, y, z)$ satisfying    the equation system $x + y + z = 0, xyz + z = 0$  and $xy + yz + zx + y = 0$?

**My partial solution**:

First simplify the $2$nd equation to be $xyz = -z$ and the $3$rd equation to be $xy + yz + zx = -y$.

We then notice something about the equations. If we let $x, y$, and $z$ be the roots of a cubic polynomial, then by Vieta's, the polynomial would be $x^3 + 0x^2 - yx + z$.

We can simplify this cubic polynomial to $x^3 - yx + z$.

Hence, we just need to solve the equation $x^3 - yx + z = 0$ for the rational numbers $x, y$, and $z$.

However, this is the part on where I am stuck with the problem. Maybe I could set values for $x$ and then solve for $y$ and $z$? I don't know.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am very confused

Comment: +1 to your question, for good work shown.  It is now moot, because of Dietrich Burde's answer, but if no one had answered, I would have suggested [cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) as the place to start.  This article may not have resolved the problem, but absent the rational root test, which I overlooked, it would have been the place to start.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* The only rational solutions are
$$
(x,y,z)=(0,0,0),(-1,1,0).
$$
To see this note that the only other case yields $x= - (z^2 + z + 1)$, $y=z^2 + 1$ with
$$
z^3+z^2+2z+1=0.
$$
By the rational root test, this cubic polynomial has no rational root.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :)